# How can I create a query that counts how many times values at two columns appear together?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a table with an user id, a video id and a status column. Every time a user watches a video it will add it to that column. I want to count how many times the user watches each video and then show the top 10 and will show as 
User ID, Video ID, X views

I have tried to look up how to do this but I can't find a good answer.

I want to count how many times the user watches each video and then show the top 10 and will show as 
User ID, Video ID, X views

```
SELECT streams.Subscriber_ID as User, streams.Video_ID, count(streams) as Views
FROM steams
JOIN streams.Subscriber_ID
ORDER BY count(streams) DESC LIMIT 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to `GROUP BY` the desired fields in order to achieve an aggregated count.

For example :

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  user_id INT,
  video_id INT
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 2), (3, 2), (3, 2), (3, 2);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT t.user_id,
       t.video_id,
       COUNT(*) AS watch
FROM test t
GROUP BY user_id, video_id
ORDER BY watch DESC;
```

**Output**

```
| user_id | video_id | watch |
| ------- | -------- | ----- |
| 3       | 2        | 4     |
| 1       | 1        | 3     |
| 1       | 2        | 1     |
| 2       | 1        | 1     |
| 2       | 2        | 1     |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bx7QjodBkPV1bnpLtGcvVV/1)